# Spock - mock a method different arguments and different return values

Tags: groovy, spock

```
given:
def someService = Mock(SomeService)

1 * someService.processInput(argument1) >> output1
1 * someservice.processInput(argument2) >> output2
```

How to make it in one statement with `with` clause with different arguments. For example:

```
2 * someService.processInput(argument1) >>> [output1, output2]
```

Comment: Just a personal opinion: Tests should be readable. Why would you want to even do that? Dmitry's answer technically does what you want, but I would not do it that way if I were you (which of course I am not).

Answer (score 4):

I believe currently it's not possible in Spock in an elegant way which you likely expected. I've only come up with something like the following:

```
def args = [arg1, arg2]
2 * service.processInput({ it == args.removeAt(0) }) >>> [out1, out2]
```

Not sure that it matches your expectations. Below is the full spec for testing this approach

```
class SOSpec extends Specification {
    def "mock a method different arguments and different return values"() {
        when:
        def arg1 = "F"
        def arg2 = "B"
        def out1 = "Foo"
        def out2 = "Bar"
        def service = Mock(SomeService) {
            def args = [arg1, arg2]
            2 * processInput({ it == args.removeAt(0) }) >>> [out1, out2]
        }

        then:
        service.processInput(arg1) == out1
        service.processInput(arg2) == out2
    }
}
```